# How do I connect a Socrata dataset to Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: socrata

Posting on behalf on a user who reached out to us via our support portal:

Is there a way to create a service reference in Microsoft Visual Studio (Like for Winforms VB.Net), from a SODA API EndPoint?

Is there any documentation for the above or any directions I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have personal experience with it, but you might be able to make use of our new OData endpoints from within Visual Studio:

http://beta.dev.socrata.com/odata/

I know that .NET can directly consume OData APIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg591296

Let us know if that helps!